# How to deal with RGB to YUV conversion

Tags: image-processing, opencv, yuv

The formula says:

```
Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B;

U = -0.14713 * R - 0.28886 * G + 0.436 * B;

V = 0.615 * R - 0.51499 * G - 0.10001 * B;
```

What if, for example, the U variable becomes negative?

```
U = -0.14713 * R - 0.28886 * G + 0.436 * B;
```

Assume maximum values for R and G (ones) and B = 0
So, I am interested in implementing this convetion function in OpenCV,
So, how to deal with negative values?
Using float image? anyway please explain me, may be I don't understand something..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert RGB<->YUV in OpenCV with [cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor) using the `code` `CV_YCrCb2RGB` for YUV->RGB and `CV_RGBYCrCb` for RGB->YUV.

```
void cvCvtColor(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int code)
```

> Converts an image from one color space
>   to another.

Comment: Thank you!! I searched for such a function and I thought that 
YCrCb is something different than YUV...

Comment: No problem. Note that you can convert 3-channel images as well. If you need to merge the Y,U and Vcomponents, you can do that with `merge` which takes a `vector<Mat>` object.

Comment: @maximus - strictly speaking it is. YUV is for analogue TV standard YCrCb is digital - the color space is different. But only very slightly

Comment: In C++: cv::cvtColor(image, yuv_image, CV_RGB2YCrCb);

Comment: Keep in mind that there is currently a bug in opencv 2.4.*, which causes incorrect convertation from RGB to YUV. *Red* and *Blue* channels are *swapped* in the implemented formula.
http://code.opencv.org/issues/4227

Comment: Look at detailed post about the bug here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29890941/1351629

Answer (score 14):

Y, U and V are all allowed to be negative when represented by decimals, according to the [YUV color plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV).

[image: YUV Color space]

Answer (score 2):

for planar formats OpenCV is not the right tool for the job.  Instead you are better off using ffmpeg. for example

```
static void rgbToYuv(byte* src, byte* dst, int width,int height)
{

    byte* src_planes[3] = {src,src + width*height, src+ (width*height*3/2)};
    int src_stride[3] = {width, width / 2, width / 2};
    byte* dest_planes[3] = {dst,NULL,NULL};
    int dest_stride[3] = {width*4,0,0};
    struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(
        width,height,
        PIX_FMT_YUV420P,width,height,PIX_FMT_RGB32,SWS_POINT,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, src_planes,src_stride,0,height,dest_planes,dest_stride); 
    sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
}
```

will convert a YUV420 image to RGB32

Comment: Interesting approach :)