# Processing .Raw images using ffmpeg or OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg, v4l2

After reading [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) of Raw image format which is the digital negative of any image.

> To be viewed or printed, the output from a camera's image sensor has
>   to be processed, that is, converted to a photographic rendering of the
>   scene, and then stored in a standard raster graphics format such as
>   JPEG. This processing, whether done in-camera or later in a raw-file
>   converter, involves a number of operations, typically including

I have some .raw files grabbed from my Logitech c920 using [v4l2 example](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) but when I display the image it looks like this:
[image: raw frame file] a raw image where in other frames I can see my shadow

Does anyone knows how to process such files to see the complete frame ?

[Here is a link to the original .raw file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-IBanqetxwNNzJYMVk0bEk1Nms/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: how did you display it ? raw probably means here, that it's not processed and that there are no 'headers' appended to it. still, it has some format. most sensors use something like yuv.  so, if you can find out, what the native format for your camer is, then it's an easy cvtColor() in opencv, to get it to nice rgb or such

Comment: I tried to convert it from yuv to rgb but I failed,this image is displayed as raw.

Comment: There are [many different ways](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php) to store and represent YUV data. It just looks like you got the wrong decoding.

Comment: Right now it is a PNG, so it is irrelevant to the problem. Include a link to the raw file.

Comment: Here is a link to the .raw file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-IBanqetxwNNzJYMVk0bEk1Nms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The image is 640x480, 16 bit big endian. if opened in photoshop using raw open and mac format, you can see an image a man with short hair wearing glasses. My guess is it is YUV data, where the high order byte of the 16 bits is the grayscale image and the low order byte contains color data. To dissect it further, i'd take some image captures of something all red, and a second image of something green and a third of something blue, then open the images in hex and see what the low order bits are doing. All black and all white would also be interesting.

Comment: There are two definitions of a raw format image. The first is a dump of pixels with no formatting applied. The second is a camera specific format containing unfiltered data from a sensor chip. The quote you give applies to second definition, but the first definition is the one that actually applies to your sample. The sensor data has already been processed into pixels and it's just a matter of determining their format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i frame-1.raw frame-1.jpg
```

The options were set based on the `v4l2` code linked, and the resulting image is the one you would expect to get.

Comment: +1 for properly decoding the format, but it would be more useful to have code to do it.

Comment: See this question for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954416/converting-yuv-into-bgr-or-rgb-in-opencv

Comment: I think it is working fine but the problem is that its resolution is very low which is not the original resolution.

Comment: @AhmedKato this is a 640x480 image, if you want a higher resolution save it in a higher resolution. The code for decoding it is there, `ffmpeg` is open source.

Comment: If I grab a 640x480 frame using ffmpeg it will be 92600kb, using your command is only 32kb.

Comment: You didn't explained why use `rawvideo`?