# processing .raw file image with ffmpeg api or C code

Tags: c, qt, image-processing, ffmpeg

I am trying to process a .raw image file captured using vrl2, it's a h264 encoded image with yuv422 color space from a Logitech c920 webcam, [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) is not working for me however from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031183/processing-raw-images-using-ffmpeg-or-opencv) this command is working fine with low performance (a 32kb jpg image however using opencv capture I get a 900kb image for the same 640x480 resolution):

> ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i frame-1.raw
>   frame-1.jpg

I need a code written in C or the ffmpeg api/OpenCV etc .. to do the same as this command,I don't want to use QProcess in Qt(I am working on a server using Qt where I am trying to send the raw file from a Raspberry PI to the server and process it their), dcraw output is a corrupted image.

Comment: why is this tagged qt??

Comment: If their is a Qt solution using QImage will be good for me since I am working using Qt.

Comment: Qt doesn't handle the different yuv types of formats. What is the exact format of your input?

Comment: yuv422 format,no problem I added Qt just in case.

Comment: I'm confused. If the command you posted is working, it's a raw YUV image, not H264.

Comment: it's working, I am using v4l2 to grab h264 frame from the cam into a yuv raw file.

Answer (score 2):

http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html

There should be some api samples in there that show how to get the image out with that specific encoding.

When interacting with a RAW file, I have also used IrfanView.  If you know the headersize of the file and the width and the height and the bits per pixel per color, you can see what it looks like quickly that way.

EDIT: I tried using Irfanview with your RAW, and I got something close, but not quite.  The coloring was always off.  I don't think it can handle that particular encoding of a RAW file right now.