# Copy AHardwareBuffer to cv::Mat opencv

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I try to convert buffer image data to `cv::Mat` `opencv` but with no success. This is the code I'm working on and when I debug the memory content of the `cv::Mat` variable I get "`read memory failed`"

[image]

```
cv::Mat* convertAHardwareBufferToMat(AHardwareBuffer* hardwareBuffer) {
    AHardwareBuffer_Desc bufferDesc;
    AHardwareBuffer_describe(hardwareBuffer, &bufferDesc);
    void* buffer = nullptr;
    int lockResult = AHardwareBuffer_lock(hardwareBuffer, AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_CPU_READ_OFTEN, -1, nullptr, &buffer);
    if (lockResult != 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "FrameProcessor", "Failed to lock hardware buffer, error: %d", lockResult);
    }

    // Create a cv::Mat and copy the data
    cv::Mat* mat = new cv::Mat(bufferDesc.height, bufferDesc.width, CV_8UC4, buffer);

    AHardwareBuffer_unlock(hardwareBuffer, nullptr);
    return mat; 
}
```

EDIT 1

I slightly changed the code to integrate the suggested solution, but the app crashes at clone line without throwing any exception, I got Step 1.1:

```
cv::Mat convertAHardwareBufferToMat(AHardwareBuffer* hardwareBuffer) {
    AHardwareBuffer_Desc bufferDesc;
    AHardwareBuffer_describe(hardwareBuffer, &bufferDesc);
    void* buffer = nullptr;
    int lockResult = AHardwareBuffer_lock(hardwareBuffer, AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_CPU_READ_OFTEN, -1, nullptr, &buffer);
    
    if (lockResult != 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "FrameProcessor", "Failed to lock hardware buffer, error: %d", lockResult);
        return cv::Mat();
    }

    // Create a cv::Mat that points to the buffer
    cv::Mat mat(bufferDesc.height, bufferDesc.width, CV_8UC4, buffer);

    cv::Mat clone;
    try {
        // Clone the Mat to make a deep copy
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FrameProcessor", "Step 1.1");
        clone = mat.clone();
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FrameProcessor", "Step 1.2");
    } catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "FrameProcessor", "cv::Exception during clone: %s", e.what());
        return cv::Mat();
    }

    // Unlock the hardware buffer as we've finished copying the data
    AHardwareBuffer_unlock(hardwareBuffer, nullptr);

    // Return the deep copy
    return clone; 
}
```

Comment: That comment lies, the `Mat` constructor you use doesn't "copy the data", the `Mat` uses the address of the buffer you got from `AHardwareBuffer_lock`. And I presume this address is only valid until you call `AHardwareBuffer_unlock`... so once the function returns, all you have is a `Mat` header with a dangling pointer to a buffer that no longer is there.

Comment: @DanMašek you are right, I missed that - my mistake.

Comment: @wohlstad Oh, I mean the comment in the code. You're absolutely right about the behaviour of the `Mat`, that's still applicable.

Comment: @DanMašek I meant I was wrong about allocating the data on the heap and keeping a ref-count on it, since the OP used the ctor that accepts an "external" data pointer (which probably becomes dangling as you wrote).

Comment: Then should I use memcpy after declaring cv::Mat* mat ?

Comment: Just do an explicit deep copy after you created the Mat (`clone()`). And as wohlstad suggested initially, return `Mat` by value (shallow copies are cheap), that raw pointer and naked `new` are just asking for a leak.

Comment: and don't use `new` or a *pointer* to a `cv::Mat`. just use the `cv::Mat`. C++, RAII.

Comment: The app crashes at clone line, I've updated my post. Looks like a problem with the buffer data or size :/

Comment: Are you sure `buffer` contains 4 bytes per pixel ? Maybe you can inspect `bufferDesc.format`.

Comment: To add to my previous comment:  I assume from `CV_8UC4` that you would like to get an RGBA image (or similar) but maybe that's not what's in `buffer`.

Comment: 4 in CV_8UC4 means the number of channels and 8 is the bytes.

Comment: @Ja_cpp yes this is what I meant. But are you sure this is the format of the data in `buffer` ?

Comment: The pixel format says: yuv: Frame is in YUV pixel-format (Y'CbCr 4:2:0 or NV21, 8-bit)
Which is correct, right?
Width: 1280, Height: 720, Layers: 1, Format: 34, Usage: 131379, stride: 1280

Comment: YUV does not fit a `CV_8UC4` pixel format.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954416/converting-yuv-into-bgr-or-rgb-in-opencv) post contains some info about converting YUV to RGB/BGR or other formats. Note that `CV_8UC1` is used for the source image, and the actual height is multiplied by 1.5 (for the 2 reduced size planes).

Comment: Note that the YUV issue is actually separate from the problem you originally had (_read memory failed_) which is addressed by my answer below. You can consider to post a new question if the post I refered to above does not help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `buffer` is valid only till the call to `AHardwareBuffer_unlock`.
At that point the pointer becomes dangling, and the `cv::Mat` that you return will still refer to it (since you used the ctor that accepts an **external** data buffer, the data is **not** copied).
A solution can be to [`clone()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a03d2a2570d06dcae378f788725789aa4) the `cv::Mat` which will allocate a new data buffer (managed by the `cv::Mat` itself and reference counted) and copy the data into it.

Another issue is the matter of `new`ing the `cv::Mat` and returning it by pointer, which is not a good practice and might cause a memory leak.
Instead you can change `convertAHardwareBufferToMat` to return the `cv::Mat` by value.

Both are demonstrated below:

```
cv::Mat convertAHardwareBufferToMat(AHardwareBuffer* hardwareBuffer) 
{
    // ...

    // Create a cv::Mat from external buffer and clone it:
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvv
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(bufferDesc.height, bufferDesc.width, CV_8UC4, buffer).clone();
    // ...

    return mat;  // return by value (cheap shalow copy, the data is ref-counted) 
}
```

---

Regarding your question update:
You need to make sure `buffer` contains 4 bytes per pixels, as expected from using the `CV_8UC4` pixel format.

**Update:**

From your last comments I understand that your source data is not in RGBA or similar format, but rather in YUV.

See this post for more info about converting from YUV: [Converting YUV into BGR or RGB in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954416/converting-yuv-into-bgr-or-rgb-in-opencv).