# Converting from YUV colour space to RGB using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, rgb, yuv

I am trying to convert a YUV image to RGB using OpenCV. I am a complete novice at this. I have created a function which takes a YUV image as source and converts it into RGB. It is like this :

```
void ConvertYUVtoRGBA(const unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dest, int width, int height)
{
    cv::Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, &src);
    cv::Mat mrgb(height, width, CV_8UC4, &dest);

    cv::cvtColor(myuv, mrgb, CV_YCrCb2RGB);
    return;
}
```

Should this work? Do I need to convert the Mat into char* again? I am in a loss and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look into  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2906294/3436942

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting YUV into BGR or RGB in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954416/converting-yuv-into-bgr-or-rgb-in-opencv)

Comment: I have already seen those posts and I was unable to use how it was specified their. Can you point out the problems with my code?

Comment: @d1xlord you have not specified which YUV format you are dealing with. Look at the following to see how many YUVs there are: fourcc.org/yuv.php. And do you really want RGB, you have specified a 4 channel Mat and the your function is called `ConvertYUVtoRGBA` so I assume you meant RGBA? Or perhaps BGRA?

Comment: @jbutler483 this should not be regarded as a duplicate of `Converting YUV into BGR or RGB in OpenCV`. Firstly I think the data here is in a different format, secondly the accepted answer of that question is, imo, not the best way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not enough detail in your question to give a certain answer but below is my best guess. I'll assume you want RGBA output (not RGB, BGR or BGRA) and that your YUV is [yuv420sp](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV21) (as this is what comes out of an Android camera, and it is consistent with your Mat sizes)

```
void ConvertYUVtoRGBA(const unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dest, int width, int height)
{
    //cv::Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, &src);
    cv::Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, src); // pass buffer pointer, not its address
    //cv::Mat mrgb(height, width, CV_8UC4, &dest);
    cv::Mat mrgb(height, width, CV_8UC4, dest);

    //cv::cvtColor(myuv, mrgb, CV_YCrCb2RGB);
    cv::cvtColor(myuv, mrgb, CV_YUV2RGBA_NV21);  // are you sure you don't want BGRA?
    return;
}
```

> *Do I need to convert the Mat into char* again?*

No the Mat mrgb is a wrapper around dest and, the way you have arranged it, the RGBA data will written directly into the dest buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I had to send &src when creating Mat, else it wasn't compiling. I also had to change it BGRA(as you suggested) and use I420 instead of NV21.
Thanks a lot for you answers once again. :D

Comment: This will only work properly if the YUV source is SD. It might look right with a basic visual inspection but the colors aren't actually correct. Unfortunately this is because the latest OpenCV source right now (2.4.10) for YUV conversion only supports the 601 colorspace of PAL/NTSC/SECAM and not 709 of HD or 2020 of UHD.

Comment: Hi, its a bit late but, how do you call this method? I have a byte array as src, the width and the height. How do i call it? I would appreciate any help. Thx