# OpenCV: cv::Mat fails to create a matrix out of seemingly valid data

Tags: c#, android, c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV for android in my project to process a YUV420 (https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV/#NV12) image. As the rest of the project is in C#, I am using GCHandles to copy an array of bytes to the C++ code. I have made sure that the data are OK in C++ by making a sum of all the bytes both in C# and C++ and comparing them. However, when I try this:

```
int foo(unsigned char * inputPtr, int width, int height) {
    cv::InputArray input_image = cv::Mat(height + height /2, width, CV_8UC1, inputPtr);

    int res = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < input_image.rows(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < input_image.cols(); x++) {
                res += (int)input_image.getMat().ptr(x + y * input_image.cols());
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

, zero is returned every time (the C# count still returns correct numbers). The sum of all bytes that returns correct values looks like this:

```
int foo(unsigned char * inputPtr, int width, int height) {
    int res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height * 1.5f; i++) {
        res += (int)inputPtr[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

The cv::Mat() arguments should be correct based on this question: [Converting from YUV colour space to RGB using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666120/converting-from-yuv-colour-space-to-rgb-using-opencv)

What reason could OpenCV have to decide not to create a matrix out of seemingly valid data?

EDIT: Forgot to add that the inputPtr pointer points to a C# byte[] with the size of (int)(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height * 1.5f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ptr return pointer but no value. Use at():

```
res += (int)input_image.getMat().at<uchar>(y, x);
```

Comment: Nope. Still returns zero.
Also if I have input_image.rows() printed out, it also says 0.

Comment: OK, try cv::sum

Comment: `return cv::sum(input_image)[0];` returns 0.

Comment: Ok, only debugging

Comment: Do you know of any way how Mat() would return an error code of some sorts? I could not find anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: Only exception with std::bad_alloc. Try to use cv::Mat instead cv::InputArray: cv::Mat input_image(height + height /2, width, CV_8UC1, inputPtr);

Comment: Thank you!
It worked, it seems that the solution is just to not keep the Mat as an Input/OutputArray but keep it as a Mat.