# Reading Frames of uncompressed yuv video file?

Tags: matlab, opencv, raspberry-pi, yuv

I recorded an uncompressed / un-encoded video in `yuv` format using camera of my `raspberry pi`. I want to **read each frame as an image** and also **count the total number of frames** of the video.

I found this answer : [How to read a frame from YUV file in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231518/how-to-read-a-frame-from-yuv-file-in-opencv) But it looks old and doesn't seem to work.

Do I have to convert `yuv` video to some other format first to read each frame. How should I go about it? 
Which tool will be better for this, `OpenCV` or `Matlab` or some other?

Comment: If it does not work, please explain the issue. It might be a minor issue simple to fix. Matlab file exchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange) contains several submissions regarding YUV.

Answer (score 1):

I think OpenCV can read YUV frames from a video file, because the underlying media handler layer (i.e. FFmpeg) does the job.

Furthermore, OpenCV also supports the conversion between [YUV and BGR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905597/how-to-deal-with-rgb-to-yuv-conversion/2906294#2906294) through [`cv::cvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) with `CV_YCrCb2RGB` or `CV_RGBYCrCb`.

Does the following code work for your videos?

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("PATH_TO_YUV");
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    std::cout << "Failed to open file: " << "PATH_TO_YUV" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

cv::Mat frame;
while(true)
{
    cap >> frame;

    if (frame.empty())             
        break;

    cv::imshow("YUV frame", frame);
    cv::waitKey(1);
}
```